# GtkMessageDialog not showing

Tags: c++, gtk, c++17, gtk3

I am creating a c++ application with the GTK+3 framework. I am trying to show a popup whenever an update is available. I've looked through the [API](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMessageDialog.html#gtk-message-dialog-new), but I cannot fix the problem I have. I do not get any error/warning/log, but my popup won't show up. I've googled a lot, but can only find people use the same code, but my popup just won't showup. My code is as following:

```
public: static void showPopup(GtkWidget* parentWindow, GtkMessageType type, GtkButtonsType buttons, const char* message)
{
    GtkWindow* parent = GTK_WINDOW(parentWindow);
    GtkDialogFlags flags = GTK_DIALOG_MODAL;
    GtkWidget* dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(parent, flags, type, buttons, "%s", message);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

This is a static meber function in a GUI class. This function is called like this:

```
public: void onUpdateResponse(int code, const char* data)
{
    std::cout<<data<<'\n';
    GUI::showPopup(this->window, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL, data);
}
```

My application does "Pause" waiting for a response of the gtk_dialog_run, but I do not see the popup window.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: According to online doc., your code looks not that bad. However, your `data`/`message` doesn't contain any `%` characters, does it? (I just noticed the _message_format printf()-style format string_ in the doc.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff, thanks for the comment. I've tried a lot since I posted this question, and also came by the formatting. I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: Did you verify in debugger that `gtk_dialog_run()` is entered? If so (and the dialog doesn't become visible) the response code would be my next check. (If you afraid debugging, a debug print to console would do as well.)

Comment: @Scheff the gtk_dialog_run() does not return anything, since it waits for a button to be clicked. I logged right before gtk_dialog_run() is called and it does log there.

Comment: Popup blocker? Sorry, I'm joking. No more ideas...

Comment: I understand, thanks for trying.

Comment: You didn't set `GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT` in flags. Is there a reason for this? (I.e. does anything happen with parent window when/while dialog is run?)

Comment: @Scheff I've tried different flags and the GTK_DIALOG_MODAL was the last I tried. All different types of flags yield the same result.

Maybe a stupid question, but is it worth noticing I am compiling on a Mac with g++?

Comment: _on a Mac_ could be worth to be mentioned in question. - My last stupid thought: Are you sure that `parentWindow` is a `GtkWindow`? (I've never tried to use `GTK_WINDOW` on a non-`GtkWindow`. So, I'm not sure if there is any debugging aid for this case.)

Comment: I am 100% sure the parentWindow is a GtkWindow. I'va also tried to make the function less generic and put al the values hard and move it to same function where I create the window, which also yields te same results.

Comment: This came just in my mind: A colleague asked me for a function to center dialogs as a customer complained that **dialogs appeared on non-connected displays**. This was especially annoying as we already check dialog positions against desktop area. It seems that the desktop of customer is larger than covered by his connected monitors. However, I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: `gtk_dialog_run` returns response code, actually. You can check it to determine, what button was pressed. Just for fun, try to create dialog with `parent` == NULL.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I've also tried that, it logs Gtk-Message: 14:47:19.259: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged. but still no popup

Comment: I now notice when I try to pass multiple flags (i.e. GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT) it shows an error becaus it returns an int. I know how bitwise operations work, but the GTK example uses the OR operator as well

Comment: _shows an error becaus it returns an int_ change type of  `flags ` variable to int, then it should work.

Comment: @Scheff I've found something. I make the popup within a non-static member function. When I call the function directly (so not as callback), the popup is shown. I still don't understant why it doesn't show the popup when its a popup since all the pointers are the same, but I got a little further.

Comment: If it is a problem to run the dialog out of a callback/signal handler than [`g_idle_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) might be an option. (I must admit that I switched from gtkmm to Qt some years ago. However, the idle-callback/timeout(0) trick works even in Qt.)

Comment: Regarding `GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT`: GTK+ is actually a C API. C is in certain cases a bit more tolerant than C++ (e.g. regarding compatibility of named `enum`s and `int`). I could imagine that certain code samples pass a C compiler without complaints but yield an error in a C++ compiler. `(GtkDialogFlags)(GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT)` should make the C++ compiler silent.

Comment: If gtk functions are called __not__ from mainloop, it's UB.

Comment: Before gtk_dialog_run() add gtk_widget_show_all(dialog); by default a widget is not visible and needs to be shown before use.

Comment: AlexanderDmitriev thank you for the answer.

Scheff Thank you for your help.

Errolvandel'Isle no.